# How to return a file in a Azure Logic Apps Custom Connector

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an action in my custom connector that responds 200 OK and a file (a pdf). In my OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 file it is defined like this:

```
    "/blogs/{blogId}/articles/{articleId}.pdf" : {
        "get" : {
            "operationId": "GetArticlePdf",
            "summary": "Find a article PDF by id",
            "description": "Returns a single article PDF",
            "produces":[
                "application/pdf"
            ],
            "parameters":[
                {
                    "name": "articleId",
                    "in": "path",
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "uuid",
                    "description": "Article Id",
                    "required": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "blogId",
                    "in" : "path",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "OK",
                    "schema":{
                        "type":"file"
                    }
                },
                "404": {
                    "description": "Not Found"
                },
                "400": {
                    "description": "Bad Request"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I use this custom connector in a Logic App, the response of this action (the file) is not listed in the dynamic content selector in the next steps.

How can I define the action so I can use its response file in the next steps as an input?

Comment: base64 encode your file and return it inside the payload

Comment: To be clear, http has no concept of a "file".  Http merely transfers "content".  It's up to the client or server app to treat content in whatever way is appropriate, including as a file.  Are you getting any content back?

Comment: @Johns-305 I agree, but I guess that Logic Apps should have a concept of “file contents”, and that should be given in the OpenAPI specification.

Comment: @Victor But that's the thing, there is no 'file content' to surface, it's just content.  There's nothing stopping the user from treating the content in any way you need.  Meaning, once the data hits the wire, there is no "file" at all.  You need to think about this one level up in abstraction.  The data only becomes a "file" when written to a file system.

Comment: Yes @Johns-305, but in this question I am taking about “one level down” in abstraction from HTTP & REST (using OpenAPI specs and Logic Apps implementation of that specs). The crux of the question is that OpenAPI allows to define that a response is a file (by using schema: type: file in the 200 response definition), but Logic Apps is not taking that into account.

Comment: @Victor That doesn't really matter.  The OpenAPI is just metadata, it's just hint on how to handle the content.  The type:file doesn't actually change the content in any way, it's still just http content.  LogicApps doesn't treat it as a "file" because LogicApps is not a file system.  If you write the content to Blob Storage, boom, you now have a "file".

Comment: Thanks @Johns-305, I now get your point. So then I should include the file as body’s content (in which encoding?) and then access that in the following steps of the Logic Apps app?

Comment: @Victor Yes, the file's *content* is include as the http body content, most likely as Base64 unless you specifically make it MIME...which is also Base64, just different.  Then it's just the body content in the LogicApp.

Comment: @Johns-305 This is completely incorrect!  Azure Logic Apps *does* have a concept of a file.  For example, Azure Blob connector only wants to take in files of a certain type.  The documentation here is non-existant so if you can provide a real example that would actually help

Comment: @Abr Except no. The question wasn't about Blobs. And I'm still 100% correct as even first class designer support doesn't mean it's a file in a Logic App.

Comment: @Johns-305 I cited Azure Blob as an example of a Connector which accepts files.  There are many other connectors that accept files as well.  And yes, HTTP does support files with Content-Disposition=attachment, etc.

Comment: @Abr Ok, but they're still not 'files'.  Huge difference.  Files exist on a File System. No, HTTP does not support 'files'.  The headers merely tell the client how to interpret the content, if it chooses to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a blob(action) and add the response of file to the blob content.

Try to writing expression to fetch the action result like:
`@body('your_custom_connector_name')` and appending the content type to blob content.

For more details, you could refer to this simple [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/68fb8f94-18da-4e0c-b3f3-68e1e806ffc8/azure-logic-apps-custom-connector-that-returns-imagepng-content-type-cannot-be-written-to-blob?forum=azurelogicapps).

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks fine definition wise.

Keep in mind, while the source might be a 'file', to http and LogicApps, it's just http content represented by the @body element.

I would expect it to be Base64 encoded unless you are specifically programming the service to do something else.