# Logic App: Display Document in WebApp and safe it to lokal computer

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

How can I solve the following problem:

Up to now, a web app fetches certain information when the user clicks on a "Create Document" button and passes it as JSON to the Logic App. The data from the JSON is used to fill in a Word template, which is then saved in Azure files storage.

How can I display this document saved in Azure to the user and give him the possibility to save it locally on his computer?

Is there a possibility with Logic Apps how I can open the document directly in a new window or that it is opened automatically in Word at the user's computer?

If this is not possible, what is the easiest way to do this with code?

Here is a picture of the Logic App

[Logic App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAyZ3.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may want to capture the details in an azure function or an web API and read the value from storage directly to save it locally. I am sharing couple of relevant links of similar scenarios:
http://www.frankysnotes.com/2017/03/passing-file-from-azure-logic-app-to.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres

You may consider custom connector as well:

[How to return a file in a Azure Logic Apps Custom Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848716/how-to-return-a-file-in-a-azure-logic-apps-custom-connector)